# Lollypop music player not starting

Tags: package-management, 20.04, software-installation, python

Lollypop was initially working fine but after a day, it's not starting.
When tried starting it from the terminal, the following message appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lollypop/application.py", line 187, in do_startup self.init()
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lollypop/application.py", line 152, in init self.scanner = CollectionScanner()
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lollypop/collection_scanner.py", line 73, in __init__ self.__history = History()
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lollypop/database_history.py", line 55, in __init__ result = sql.execute("SELECT COUNT(*)\
sqlite3.DatabaseError: file is not a database
```

I tried rebooting, reinstalling, installing a previous version. Nothing fixes it.
Weirdly, it starts properly when started with `sudo` from the terminal.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my friend. [These](https://www.imaginelinux.com/install-latest-lollypop-music-player-ubuntu/) instructions look pretty good and they work.

I hope they help.

Comment: thanks , installed with flatpak and it works!